# Array.concat reflects the change in resulting array when input nested array is modified after concatination

Tags: javascript, arrays

According to MDN, the description for concat is as below,

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method
>   does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

Consider the below code,

Example 1

```js
const array1 = [['a'], 'b', 'c'];
const array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

const array3 = array1.concat(array2); // concatinate array1 and array2 and returns new array3.

console.log(array3);

array1.push('pushed'); // pushed as the last element to the array1

console.log(array3); // no change in array 3, looks correct
```

output

```
[["a"], "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]  
[["a"], "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Example 2:

```js
const array1 = [['a'], 'b', 'c'];
const array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

const array3 = array1.concat(array2); // concatinate array1 and array2 and returns new array3.

console.log(array3);

array1[0].push('pushed'); // pushed as the last element to the nested array at position 0

console.log(array3); // array 3 also changed, why?
```

output

```
[["a"], "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]  
[["a", "pushed"], "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

In the example 2, why did the content of `array3` got changed even though the concatenation happened before the push of new element in `array1`.

**NOTE**: the only difference between the 2 examples is
Example1: `array1.push('pushed')`
Example2: `array1[0].push('pushed')`

I understand about pass by value and pass by reference (and arrays and objects share reference), but the thing which confused me is why is the nested array sharing reference and the original array was copied.

Comment: The resulting array does not reflect changes to the input. What does change however, is an element, that is an element of both the resulting array, and the input.

Comment: `Array.concat()` doesn't clone the elements it combines, hence `array[0] === array3[0]`

Comment: In javascript array/object is copied by reference. that's the reason for the change in resulted array.

Comment: the second example shows the change in the resulting array @ASDFGerte

Comment: https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Comment: @Uthaya Seelan, according to MDN, the concat method will not modify the input arrays and it returns new copy

Comment: Lets say you have a list, written on a paper, of house addresses. You tell someone to copy that list. Now you have two paper lists of house addresses. Now you raze one of the buildings to the ground, and give one of the lists to one person, and the other to another, telling both, to check the houses. They will both find a razed house, although the lists (which were set on paper, and not edited), never changed.

Comment: concat returns a new array of elements but does not create a copy of each element as well. Know the difference between `shallow copy` and `deep copy`.

Comment: _"...and it returns new **copy**"_ - Where did you find the _"copy"_? `Array.concat()` will neither modify `array1` nor `array2`. For this to work it has to create/return a new one where it adds the elements from `array1` and `array2`

Comment: @Tick20 if you know the difference between deep and shallow copy then you should understand this statement: the nested array has been shallowly copied to the output array and this is why changes to this array "affect" input array

Comment: My above comment may not precisely reflect the situation at hand, but shine light on what's happening: You are editing an element, which is part of both arrays. The arrays themselves don't change at all, but they both include a reference to the same other array, which you then mutate.

Comment: Think of it this way. `const inner = ["a"], array1 = [inner, 'b', 'c']` When you concat, a new array is created by just copying the values of the both the arrays. It's just that one of the values is an array. `array1[0] === array3[0]`. They are both still pointing to the same reference. When you do `array1[0].push()`, you are changing `inner`. Any changes to `inner` will affect where it is referenced.

Comment: @Tick20 Arrays are passed by reference, you have two plates(arrays) of sweets(elements), and you are putting all the sweets into a third plate(arrays), now if the sweet(element) is an array or object  then it will retain its reference of the first plate itself

Comment: Thank you all, everyones explanation were so good, and i guess i liked how @adiga explained.

Comment: As another note, a good and extensive tutorial (one that isn't aimed at "get started quick") should explain this in great detail. Sadly, i don't know one, and don't have time to read through and analyze dozens of tutorials, to find one. I know the one which shows up on top in google (a certain w3......) is terrible, but that doesn't help much. I could provide a tutorial for c++, which will include the reasons for this, but one for javascript would really be nice to have at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element at index `0` in `array1` (a **non primitive**) was copied by reference in the new array returned by `array1.concat(array2)` and stored in `array3`.

`.push()` mutates the array in place. When you mutate `array1`, it does not affect `array3` because they do not share the same reference (`concat` returned a new array).

But because the element at index `0` in `array1` (a **non primitive**) is sharing the same reference as the element at index `0` in `array3` (which you can check by seeing that `array1[0] === array3[0]; // true`), mutating that array in `array1` is mutating the same array in `array3`.

TLDR: `array1 !== array3` but `array1[0] === array3[0]`

Comment: Thank you and i am sorry but still i am trying to understand why would it keep references for NESTED arrays and not for the original one, or if i am right, why would it shallow copy the nested array and deep copy the original array?

Comment: @Tick20 A shallow copy will only duplicate primitive values (numbers, booleans, strings), but will only copy the reference of complex types (objects, arrays, promises, functions, etc...)

Comment: @Seblor, ok, but when we take this case, both are arrays, and main array is copied by value while the nested array is referenced.

Comment: `concat` creates a shallow copy, copying only the reference of the nested array.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand about pass by value and pass by reference (and array and objects share reference), but the thing which confused me is why is the nested array sharing reference and the original array was copied.

That's how [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) works, it returns **copies of the same elements** in a **new array**.

You can do the same thing using [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const array3 = [...array1, ...array2];
```

We have copies of the same elements from `array1` and `array2` but in a new array `[]`, so if an element is an array or an object it'll be copied by reference

Look at this example:

```js
const array1 = [['a'], 'b', 'c'];

const array3 = array1.concat();

console.log('array3:', array3);

console.log('array3 === array1 ? :', array3 === array1);
console.log('array3[0] === array1[0] ? :', array3[0] === array1[0]);
```

The same example using `Spread syntax`:

```js
const array1 = [['a'], 'b', 'c'];

const array3 = [...array1];

console.log('array3:', array3);

console.log('array3 === array1 ? :', array3 === array1);
console.log('array3[0] === array1[0] ? :', array3[0] === array1[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from those good answers posted above, Here is an interesting and a well explained article about deep and shallow copy.

[how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies by Lukas Gisder-Dubé](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd/)